# C++, Programa não resolve todas as Instancias!

Tags: c++

Olá, boa noite.
Estou no primeiro período de ciência da computação, minha universidade tem um site próprio que avalia o seu código e te da uma nota de 0 a 100, porém ocorre que nesse código abaixo eu recebo 93,3, e o site diz que o programa não resolve tudo que é preciso.
**Apenas estou usando tudo que foi ensinando,eu quero saber onde está errado, ou oque ta faltando. Muito obrigado!**
[image: Esse é o problema]

Esse é o meu codigo;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int codigo;
float salarioatual,aumento,novosalario;
cin>>codigo>>salarioatual;  

switch (codigo){
    case (1):
    aumento=salarioatual*0.5;
    novosalario=salarioatual+aumento;
    cout<<"Escrituario"<<endl<<aumento<<endl<<novosalario;
    break;
    case (2):
    aumento=salarioatual*0.35;
    novosalario=salarioatual+aumento;
    cout<<"Secretario"<<endl<<aumento<<endl<<novosalario;
    break;
    case(3):
    aumento=salarioatual*0.20;
    novosalario=salarioatual+aumento;
    cout<<"Caixa"<<endl<<aumento<<endl<<novosalario;
    break;
    case(4):
    aumento=salarioatual*0.10;
    novosalario=salarioatual+aumento;
    cout<<"Gerente"<<endl<<aumento<<endl<<novosalario;
    break;
    case(5):
    aumento=salarioatual*0;
    novosalario=salarioatual+aumento;
    cout<<"Diretor"<<endl<<aumento<<endl<<novosalario;
    break;
    default:
    cout<<"Codigo nao definido";
 }  
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Qual seu problema? Também tem como postar o seu código de modo textual, no lugar de um print o qual não podemos interagir com ele?

Comment: eu tentei postar textual e saiu pela metade, qual é a forma que eu posto textual? o problema é que o site vê um erro nele entendeu, tem alguma questão que ele não resolve, e eu não consigo enxergar esse questão!

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto e vai funcionar conforme o enunciado.

Porém, como se trata de um trabalho acadêmico, acredito que o intento do problema é que a equação de primeiro grau que envolve o cálculo de porcentagens seja implementada no código.

Na sua implementação, ao invés de você usar as porcentagens diretamente, você pré-calculou o coeficiente do aumento de salário, por exemplo: `0.5` no lugar de `50%`, `0.35` no lugar de `35%`, e assim por diante...

Sugiro que você implemente a "Regra de Três" que é o cerne da resolução do problema, talvez assim você ganhe a nota máxima, por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int cod = 0;
    const char * cargo = NULL;
    float salario = 0.0;
    float percentual = 0.0;
    float aumento = 0.0;
    float novosalario = 0.0;

    // Entrada
    std::cin >> cod >> salario;

    // Identifica o codigo do cargo
    switch( cod ) {
        case 1: percentual = 50; cargo = "Escriturario"; break;
        case 2: percentual = 35; cargo = "Secretario"; break;
        case 3: percentual = 20; cargo = "Caixa"; break;
        case 4: percentual = 10; cargo = "Gerente"; break;
        case 5: percentual = 0; cargo = "Diretor"; break;
        default: cargo = "Codigo do cargo nao definido."; break;
    }

    /* Calcula novo Salario */
    aumento = salario * (percentual / 100.0);
    novosalario = salario + aumento;

    /* Saida */
    std::cout << cargo << std::endl << aumento << std::endl << novosalario << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Engraçado, que os dois fazem as mesmas funções, e como você disse, deu 100, muito obrigado!, Você pode me explicar pra que serve a biblioteca string ?

Comment: @VictorOliveiraSilva: Foi apenas um vício meu usar o tipo padrão `std::string` para guardar textos, por isso a necessidade do `#include <string>`. Mas, nesse caso, a coisa pode ser mais simples e um ponteiro `const char` pode ser usado. Veja minha edição.

Comment: @VictorOliveiraSilva: Uma observação curiosa é o fato de que o programa que você escreveu é *teoricamente* **mais eficiente** que o programa da minha resposta. Isso acontece pois ele não realiza a divisão por `100`, na verdade, essa divisão foi pre-calculada "dentro da sua cabeça", poupando o computador de ter que executar essa "árdua" tarefa.

Comment: entendi, é bem interessante, o site aqui da faculdade tem muito dessas coisas que não fazem muito sentido, e ai a gente tem que ir se adaptando a ele, pois ele é quem da nota kkkk!! Valeu cara!

Answer (score 0):

Como mera curiosidade, mostro outra forma de resolver o problema, utilizando arrays para os percentuais e para os cargos, evitando assim o `switch`. Para tornar ainda mais interessante optei retirar quase todas as variáveis de calculo intermédio e compactei drasticamente a escrita.

Atenção que esta certamente não será a forma esperada para resolver o exercício e é possível que obtenha uma nota ainda inferior, mas ainda assim, segue o exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int cod; float salario;
    const char cargos[5][20] = {{"Escriturario"},{"Secretario"},{"Caixa"},{"Gerente"},{"Diretor"}};
    const float percentuais[] = { 0.5f, 0.35f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 0};

    cin>>cod>>salario;
    if ((--cod)>=0 || cod<=4)
        cout<<cargos[cod]<<endl<<percentuais[cod]*100<<endl<<(1+percentuais[cod])*salario<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Codigo do cargo nao definido.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bem interessante, no caso aqui, eu tenho que usar o Switch porque estamos aprendendo as estruturas de repetição, então todos exercícios, tenho que usar, switch ou if else.
Porém, esse método parece mais complexo olhando de primeira vez, mas da muito menos trabalho e é muito interessante, acredito que eu ainda vou aprender isso!!
Valeu por mostrar outro modo!